# How to get difference in years from current date and Ecto.Date instance

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Let's say I have a `Person` model and each person has a birthday field set as an `Ecto.Date` column.

So if I retrieve a record from the database which represents an instance of this model, what is the best way to get this person's age from his `birthday` column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about 'best way', but this is *a* way:

```
defmodule AgeCalc do
  @spec age(Ecto.Date.t, atom|{integer, integer, integer}) :: integer
  def age(%Ecto.Date{day: d, month: m, year: y}, as_of \\ :now) do
    do_age({y, m, d}, as_of)
  end

  ###########
  # Internals
  ###########
  @doc false
  def do_age(birthday, :now) do
    {today, _time} = :calendar.now_to_datetime(:erlang.now)
    calc_diff(birthday, today)
  end
  def do_age(birthday, date), do: calc_diff(birthday, date)

  @doc false
  def calc_diff({y1, m1, d1}, {y2, m2, d2}) when m2 > m1 or (m2 == m1 and d2 >= d1) do
    y2 - y1
  end
  def calc_diff({y1,_,_}, {y2,_,_}), do: (y2 - y1) - 1
end
```

Usage goes like this: (today is September 27th, 2015)

```
iex(1)> AgeCalc.age(%Ecto.Date{day: 27, month: 9, year: 2000})
15
iex(2)> AgeCalc.age(%Ecto.Date{day: 28, month: 9, year: 2000})
14
```

or, for a manual calculation against something other than today:

```
iex(3)> AgeCalc.age(%Ecto.Date{day: 28, month: 9, year: 2000}, {2034, 12, 25})
34
```

Comment: There are several libraries for general purpose date/time calcutions. Timex is one I am familiar with. https://github.com/bitwalker/timex

Comment: I use vanilla Timex often- looking through the docs I found [:timex_ecto](https://timex.readme.io/docs/using-with-ecto), which seems like a good option, though I haven't used it myself, and it might need a fair amount of re-tooling based on the examples.

Answer (score 2):

I use [`fragment`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1) from Ecto's Query API. I have a user table with a birthday column and am using the following query:

```
Repo.all(from u in User, select: fragment("age(?)", u.birthday))
```

The query returns a [`%Postgrex.Interval{}`](https://hexdocs.pm/postgrex/Postgrex.Interval.html) with fields `days`, `months`, and `secs`. Take months and `div` by 12 to get the age.

I love Timex but using Postgres' native `age` function seems cleaner and quicker to me.

Comment: It may be quicker, however you are introducing SQL specific only to postgres and if you decide to migrate to another engine your code won't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I did it in elixir like this

```
  def calculate_age(dob) when is_binary(dob)
  def calculate_age(dob) when is_binary(dob) do
    today = Date.utc_today()
    dob = Date.from_iso8601! dob
    today.year - dob.year
  end
```

Comment: it will return wrong age when you have not birthday this year yet.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old but I just ran into this and wrote my own function which I think is a bit easier to understand, using [`Date`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Date.html) from Elixir [which has since replaced](https://dashbit.co/blog/a-sneak-peek-at-ecto-3-0-breaking-changes/) `Ecto.Date`:

```
def get_person_age(%Person{} = person) do
  today = Date.utc_today()
  {:ok, today_in_birthday_year} = Date.new(person.birthday.year, today.month, today.day)
  years_diff = today.year - person.birthday.year

  if Date.compare(today_in_birthday_year, person.birthday) == :lt do
    years_diff - 1
  else
    years_diff
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried out the Timex library as suggested in some earlier comments and answers and was able to calculate the age like this:

```
Timex.diff(Timex.now, dob, :year)
```

https://hexdocs.pm/timex/Timex.html#diff/3